# How to Import CA cert to pkcs12

Tags: openssl

I am wondering if it is possible to import CA certificate in .p12 file.

I google it and found that maybe it is possible, but how?

Thanks

Comment: http://mihail.stoynov.com/2009/03/12/certificates-keystores-java-keytool-utility-and-openssl/

Comment: I didn't think if some one will answer it.
Thanks in advance.
It is correct.

Answer (score 8):

*Eli Rosencruft*'s link contains lots of commands. In essence, this is how you import a CA cert into pkcs12 using java's {keytool}:

```
$ keytool -importcert -noprompt \
          -keystore [keystore name].p12 -storepass [keystore pass] \
          -alias [name of cert in keystore] -file [cert file to import].pem
```

Comment: Another way for importing a CA cert (and its key pair) without relying on java: `openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey key.pem -in certificate.pem -name [name of cert in keystore] -out keystore.p12 -passout "pass:[keystore pass]"`

Comment: This openssl command creates keystore.p12 rather than adding it to an existing keystore.p12.

Comment: @divanov well spotted: this `openssl` will indeed overwrite the contents of your p12.

Comment: I searched the web, but could not find an openssl command that would add to an existing p12 file; the only option available seams to create/overwrite the p12 file.  If I am wrong, please provide an example on how to add to a p12 file.

Comment: I was able to import a cert/key pair using the https://keystore-explorer.org/ app. That's not via cli though.